# Trying to calculate the time complexity of the following piece of code

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Is the time complexity of the following piece of code `O(n^5)`? My reasoning is that the outer for loop is `O(n)`, the middle for loop is `O(n^2)` since the value of i is based on the value of n, and the inner for loop is `O(n^2)` since the value of j is based on the value if i^2 which is based on the value of n^2.

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i * i; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's `O(n^5)`, there are many series of sums here, but after simplification the highest power above `n` will be 5.

Comment: Does seem a bit confusing, but I make it `o(n^4)`, what is this in relation to anyway?

Comment: @BillNaylor please have a look at my calculations below. It's `O(n^5)`

Comment: Did my answer help you Justin?

Comment: Wolfram alpha is good at sums: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28sum%28j+for+j+%3D+0+...+i%5E2-1%29+for+i+%3D+0+..+n-1%29

Comment: @PaulHankin and when you buy a mobile app for android or iOS you get a premium with the step by step solution when needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not that simple. To determine the complexity, one needs to calculate how many times the `x` will increase.

```
The most inner loop runs `j` times.
The middle loop runs `i*i` times.
The outer loop runs n times.
```

Let's reduce:

The middle loop's complexity is:

```
1+2+3+...+(i-1)+i+(i+1)+...+(i-1)*(i-1) = (i^2-2i+1)*i*i/2=(i^4-2i^3+i^2)/2
```

And the outer loop runs `n` times for each n from 0 to `n-1`. It sums up to:

```
n^5/10 - n^4/2 + 5n^3/6 - n^2/2 + n/15
```

and it's actually `O(n^5)`.

The mathematical notation is:

[image]